# ListItem get deselected on Button click

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, 2016, ctx

There's a web part on a **list view** page with button element on it. When user clicks the **button** all selected list items get deselected.
I cannot change **button** element to **input** because it's **Office UI Fabric** component.
I added ***type='button'*** attribute to the **button** so it won't reload the page, but it didn't help with selection.
Any ideas?

Here's code I place to AllItems.aspx page. On button click all selected items get deselected:

```
<button type='button' onclick='test();return false;' >test</button>
<script>
function test() {
//nothing here
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it. Dont forget to change web part id (MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 - id of list view web part) if it doesn't work:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");
if (elem != null) {
    var dummyevent = new Array();
    dummyevent["target"] = elem;
    dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
    WpClick(dummyevent);
    SP.Ribbon.WebPartComponent.$3.deselectWebPartAndZone = function () { };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `return false;` to the button onclick. That should prevent the postback.

Comment: Already tried! Kindly check edited first message, do I miss something?